# Compute shader pipeline creation crash

Tags: c++, vulkan

I'm trying to create a pipeline for a compute shader.

The program crashes at the "vkCreateComputePipelines" line without anything in the validation layers.

Here's the code :

```
/* Pipeline layout */
VkPipelineLayoutCreateInfo pipelineLayoutInfo = {};
pipelineLayoutInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_LAYOUT_CREATE_INFO;
pipelineLayoutInfo.setLayoutCount = 1;
pipelineLayoutInfo.pSetLayouts = descriptorSetLayout;
pipelineLayoutInfo.pushConstantRangeCount = 0;

if (vkCreatePipelineLayout(vk->getDevice(), &pipelineLayoutInfo, nullptr, &m_pipelineLayout) != VK_SUCCESS)
    throw std::runtime_error("Error : pipeline layout creation");

/* Shader */
std::vector<char> computeShaderCode = readFile(computeShader);
VkShaderModule computeShaderModule = createShaderModule(computeShaderCode, vk->getDevice());

VkPipelineShaderStageCreateInfo compShaderStageInfo = {};
compShaderStageInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_SHADER_STAGE_CREATE_INFO;
compShaderStageInfo.stage = VK_SHADER_STAGE_COMPUTE_BIT;
compShaderStageInfo.module = computeShaderModule;
compShaderStageInfo.pName = "main";

/* Pipeline */
VkComputePipelineCreateInfo pipelineInfo;
pipelineInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_COMPUTE_PIPELINE_CREATE_INFO;
pipelineInfo.stage = compShaderStageInfo;
pipelineInfo.layout = m_pipelineLayout;

if (vkCreateComputePipelines(vk->getDevice(), VK_NULL_HANDLE, 1, &pipelineInfo, nullptr, &m_computePipeline) != VK_SUCCESS)
    throw std::runtime_error("Error : compute pipeline creation");
```

The description set layout is created here :

```
VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding inputImageLayoutBinding = {};
inputImageLayoutBinding.binding = 0;
inputImageLayoutBinding.descriptorType = VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_STORAGE_IMAGE;
inputImageLayoutBinding.descriptorCount = 1;
inputImageLayoutBinding.stageFlags = VK_SHADER_STAGE_COMPUTE_BIT;
inputImageLayoutBinding.pImmutableSamplers = nullptr;

VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding outputImageLayoutBinding = {};
outputImageLayoutBinding.binding = 1;
outputImageLayoutBinding.descriptorType = VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_STORAGE_IMAGE;
outputImageLayoutBinding.descriptorCount = 1;
outputImageLayoutBinding.stageFlags = VK_SHADER_STAGE_COMPUTE_BIT;
outputImageLayoutBinding.pImmutableSamplers = nullptr;

std::vector<VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding> descriptorSetLayouts = { inputImageLayoutBinding, outputImageLayoutBinding };

VkDescriptorSetLayoutCreateInfo layoutInfo = {};
layoutInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DESCRIPTOR_SET_LAYOUT_CREATE_INFO;
layoutInfo.bindingCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(descriptorSetLayouts.size());
layoutInfo.pBindings = descriptorSetLayouts.data();

VkDescriptorSetLayout descriptorSetLayout;
if (vkCreateDescriptorSetLayout(vk->getDevice(), &layoutInfo, nullptr, &descriptorSetLayout) != VK_SUCCESS)
    throw std::runtime_error("Erreur : descriptor set layout");
```

The compute shader code :

```
#version 450
#extension GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects : enable

layout (local_size_x = 16, local_size_y = 16) in;

layout (binding = 0, rgba8) uniform readonly image2D inputImage;
layout (binding = 1, rgba8) uniform image2D resultImage;

void main()
{   
    float blurImpact = 1.0;

    ivec2 offsets[9] = ivec2[](
        ivec2(-1, 1), // top-left
        ivec2(0, 1), // top-center
        ivec2(1, 1), // top-right
        ivec2(-1, 0),   // center-left
        ivec2(0, 0),   // center-center
        ivec2(1, 0),   // center-right
        ivec2(-1, -1), // bottom-left
        ivec2(0, -1), // bottom-center
        ivec2(0, -1)  // bottom-right    
    );
    float kernel[9] = float[](
        blurImpact, 2.0 * blurImpact, blurImpact,
        2.0 * blurImpact,  4.0, 2.0 * blurImpact,
        blurImpact, 2.0 * blurImpact, blurImpact
    );
    float sum = 12.0 * blurImpact + 4.0;

    vec3 resultColor = vec3(0.0);

    for(int i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
    {
        resultColor += imageLoad(inputImage, ivec2(gl_GlobalInvocationID.x + offsets[i].x, gl_GlobalInvocationID.y + offsets[i].y)).rgb * (kernel[i] / sum);
    }

    imageStore(resultImage, ivec2(gl_GlobalInvocationID.xy), vec4(resultColor, 1.0));
}
```

I've tried to add a pipeline cache but that doesn't fix the problem. From the specification (https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/man/html/vkCreateComputePipelines.html), I think this parameter is optionnal.

Thanks !

Comment: The Chronos documentation mentions that `vkCreateComputePipelines` returns either success or one of three error codes that indicate an out of memory situation or an invalid shader handle. You could log the return result code or add it to your exception message. I'm not sure if the Vulkan API has a `getLastError` function that could give you more info, however, the [documentation mentions](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/man/html/VkResult.html) that the Vulkan API does _not_ capture error information about API misuse (e.g. wrong parameters).

Comment: The function makes an exception (read access violation) before returning a result

Comment: So I guess you might be passing in a bad pointer. How is `m_computePipeline` set up? Is it properly initialized?

Comment: The "vkCreateComputePipelines" function need to initialize "m_computePipeline". Specs say : "pPipelines is a pointer to an array of VkPipeline handles in which the resulting compute pipeline objects are returned."

Comment: `vkCreateComputePipelines` populates that array, but it does not initialize it. You need to initialize it beforehand and it has to have the right size. From the documentation: "pPipelines must be a valid pointer to an array of createInfoCount VkPipeline handles".

Comment: I don't understand how I'm supposed to initialize m_computePipeline, I'm not creating it dynamically : "VkPipeline m_computePipeline;". In this example : https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan/blob/master/examples/computeshader/computeshader.cpp (line 577), there is not any function before "vkCreateComputePipelines" that initialize the VkPipeline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `VkComputePipelineCreateInfo pipelineInfo;` is not zeroed. Therefore `pNext` can be garbage. Therefore it may cause dereferencing of garbage pointer by the driver or layers.

Comment: Thank you for your response ! I added `pipelineInfo.pNext = nullptr; pipelineInfo.basePipelineHandle = VK_NULL_HANDLE;` and it works now